# setting a string for each entry in response

Tags: php

I am using the following code to extract the certificate chain from a website. The code works fine but what it does is take all the certificates and it bundles them up into one string $pem_encoded.

What I would like to do is set a different string for each certificate, how can I do this?

```
        $cont = @stream_context_get_params($result);
        foreach($cont["options"]["ssl"]["peer_certificate_chain"] as $cert) {
            openssl_x509_export($cert, $pem_encoded);
            print_r($pem_encoded);
        }
    }
```

The output for `print_r($pem_encoded);` will look something like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
KwYBBQUHAwIwGQYDVR0RBBIwEIIOd3d3Lmdvb2dsZS5jb20waAYIKwYBBQUHAQEE
XDBaMCsGCCsGAQUFBzAChh9odHRwOi8vcGtpLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vR0lBRzIuY3J0
MCsGCCsGAQUFBzABhh9odHRwOi8vY2xpZW50czEuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS9vY3NwMB0G
A1UdDgQWBBSgAQj1VB+R5iA9ZysggEXxg+oRFzAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMB8GA1Ud
/A6Yfa2DF67oyHZKXuogVwko+cfVe91v+aAQVyltkzAcZy/xaypI8WFj
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
VaTOgmKV7utZX8bhBYASxF6UP7xbSDj0U/ck5vuR6RXEz/RTDfRK/J9U3n2+oGtv
h8DQUB8oMANA2ghzUWx//zo8pzcGjr1LEQTrfSTe5vn8MXH7lNVg8y5Kr0LSy+rE
ahqyzFPdFUuLH8gZYR/Nnag+YyuENWllhMgZxUYi+FOVvuOAShDGKuy6lyARxzmZ
EASg8GF6lSWMTlJ14rbtCMoU/M4iarNOz0YDl5cDfsCx3nuvRTPPuj5xt970JSXC
VOBHBw==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
AxMSR2VvVHJ1c3QgR2xvYmFsIENBMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIB
CgKCAQEA2swYYzD99BcjGlZ+W988bDjkcbd4kdS8odhM+KhDtgPpTSEHCIjaWC9m
OSm9BXiLnTjoBbdqfnGk5sRgprDvgOSJKA+eJdbtg/OtppHHmMlCGDUUna2YRpIu
T8rxh0PBFpVXLVDviS2Aelet8u5fa9IAjbkU+BQVNdnARqN7csiRv8lVK83Qlz6c
JmTM386DGXHKTubU1XupGc1V3sjs0l44U+VcT4wt/lAjNvxm5suOpDkZALeVAjmR
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I would like to programmatically seat each certificate as a separate string. Each certificate begins with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and ends with `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` In this case as there is three certificates, I would like 3 strings.

Comment: In case `$pem_encoded` is a string and the output you've shared is the output of "one round" of the loop, you can use `preg_match` against the constant "start" and "end" statements.

Comment: That's is correct, its one round and returning all certificates concatenated in one string. thx for your advice of using preg_match - do you have any example of that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this, it will catch separately every certificate.

```
<?php
$str = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
KwYBBQUHAwIwGQYDVR0RBBIwEIIOd3d3Lmdvb2dsZS5jb20waAYIKwYBBQUHAQEE
XDBaMCsGCCsGAQUFBzAChh9odHRwOi8vcGtpLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vR0lBRzIuY3J0
MCsGCCsGAQUFBzABhh9odHRwOi8vY2xpZW50czEuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS9vY3NwMB0G
A1UdDgQWBBSgAQj1VB+R5iA9ZysggEXxg+oRFzAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMB8GA1Ud
/A6Yfa2DF67oyHZKXuogVwko+cfVe91v+aAQVyltkzAcZy/xaypI8WFj
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
VaTOgmKV7utZX8bhBYASxF6UP7xbSDj0U/ck5vuR6RXEz/RTDfRK/J9U3n2+oGtv
h8DQUB8oMANA2ghzUWx//zo8pzcGjr1LEQTrfSTe5vn8MXH7lNVg8y5Kr0LSy+rE
ahqyzFPdFUuLH8gZYR/Nnag+YyuENWllhMgZxUYi+FOVvuOAShDGKuy6lyARxzmZ
EASg8GF6lSWMTlJ14rbtCMoU/M4iarNOz0YDl5cDfsCx3nuvRTPPuj5xt970JSXC
VOBHBw==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
AxMSR2VvVHJ1c3QgR2xvYmFsIENBMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIB
CgKCAQEA2swYYzD99BcjGlZ+W988bDjkcbd4kdS8odhM+KhDtgPpTSEHCIjaWC9m
OSm9BXiLnTjoBbdqfnGk5sRgprDvgOSJKA+eJdbtg/OtppHHmMlCGDUUna2YRpIu
T8rxh0PBFpVXLVDviS2Aelet8u5fa9IAjbkU+BQVNdnARqN7csiRv8lVK83Qlz6c
JmTM386DGXHKTubU1XupGc1V3sjs0l44U+VcT4wt/lAjNvxm5suOpDkZALeVAjmR
-----END CERTIFICATE-----'; // The certificates string
preg_match_all('/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----[^-]*-----END CERTIFICATE-----/s', $str, $matches);

foreach ($matches[0] as $match)
{
    echo $match;
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: thanks Heru-Luin, this looks promising.. i am getting each cert returned in an array now but is it correct that each certificate entry is showing up as  `[0] => ` shouldnt it be in increment ? as I want to access each certificate seperately

Comment: I guess my question is since each array has label as [0] how can I reference it externally ?

Comment: Edited.
I added a foreach loop to show you how you can access each certificate string. Also simplified the regex.

Comment: perfect. thats exactly what i needed. thanks for bearing with me.